# How to use string constants in my own functions?

Tags: c, linux, unix

I want to make a function, that prints environment variables with a color.

The body of function is simple:

```
char * var = (char *) getenv ("<name of variable>") // getting a pointer to the first character of constant
for (int i = 0; var[i] != 0; i++)
{
    printf ("%s%c",  <color escape sequence>, var[i]); 
}
```

But I haven't found how to get a string constant from another function to use it instead of "<name of variable>" and "<color escape sequence>".
I want my function to be used like this:

```
print_env ("USER", "\x18[35m"); // print $USER in magenta
/* "\x18[35m" is an escape secuence of magenta */
```

UPD:

Example of int main() using this construction:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAG  "\x1B[35m"

/*--------------------int main---------------------*/
int main()
{
    char * var = (char *) getenv ("HOME") // getting a pointer to the first character of constant
    for (int i = 0; var[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        printf ("%s%c",  MAG, var[i]); 
    }
    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

And in my case it shows like this (the colour of it is actually magenta):

```
/home/andrew
```

Comment: Just use the variables that the function declaration has instead of the literal strings.

Comment: How is the declaration of the function? You give it the arguments so you can use them in the function directly, so I don’t understand the problem. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Your escape code (`"\x18[35m"`) is wrong - It should be `"\x1B[35m"`  https://onlinegdb.com/McfB1j55e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string constant just turns into a `const char *` wherever you use it in C.  So you'd define your function as taking those as arguments:

```
void print_env(const char *varname, const char *esc_seq) {
    char *var = getenv(varname);
    if (var)
        printf("%s%s\x1b[0m", esc_seq, var);
}
```

Now you can call this as

```
print_env("USER", "\x1b[35m");
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
void print_env(const char *env_name, const char *esc_start) {
     char * env_val = getenv(env_name);
     printf("%s%s : %s%s\n", esc_start, env_name, env_val, esc_stop);
// esc_stop could be e.g. \u001b[0m
}
```